# Endpoint throwing "Required request body is missing: public boolean" when boolean not requested

Tags: java, spring-boot

The following is a generic "Send an email to a user" endpoint, in a java application with SpringBoot framework.

[image]

Hitting it manually with Postman works as intended, but hitting it from the mobile frontend (largely react JS based) with the following JSON:

```
{recipientAddress: 'sample@gmail.com', subjectLine: 'a', messageBody: 's'}
```

Throws the following error:

```
Required request body is missing: public boolean 
    [. . .].Controllers.API.ApplicationUserController.sendEmail([. . .].Models.DTOs.EmailDTO)
```

I don't know where this would be coming from, as the RequestBody does not have a boolean, and the DTO it does request also does not have a boolean anywhere in it. The only boolean involved is the return value, but that wouldn't be relevant to the exception in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not use GET with payload as `{recipientAddress: 'sample@gmail.com',...}`

you can either:

1. change `@GetMapping("/SendEmail")` to `@PostMapping("/SendEmail")` and send an object (don't forget `content-type` header)

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/SendEmail -d '{"recipientAddress": "sample@gmail.com", "subjectLine": "a", "messageBody": "s"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

(on postman make sure to change http method to POST)

2. keep `@GetMapping` but break you payload into query params:

```sh
curl "http://localhost:8080/SendEmail?recipientAddress=sample@gmail.com&subjectLine=a&messageBody=s"
```

(assuming localhost:8080)

last you did not specify if you use class level annotation `@RestController` or `@Controller`, if you use `@Controller` - you should also add `@ResponseBody` on method level (use `@RestController` if you can)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `@RequestBody`. If your DTO will look like this

```
public class EmailDTO{
  private String recipientAddress;
  private String subjectLine;
  private String messageBody;
  //add getters and setters (MANDATORY)
}
```

and if you send all your params as query params, it will work

if you are indeed need to sent JSON than probably you wanted `@PostMapping` not `@GetMapping`